# Rashi font with Nekudot for download?

Tags: product-recommendation

Where can I find a "Rashi script" Hebrew font ***with Nekudot*** available for download? Interested in either free or paid purchases.

Comment: I'm not by a computer to check, however check out opensiddur fonts and SIL fonts. They should have one available.

Comment: @ezra's answer is what I'd suggest, although Koren also makes a Rashi script, which may be gotten from MasterFont, if you'd prefer <https://www.masterfont.co.il/KorenRashi-Regular>

Comment: @NoachMiFrankfurt That's an odd-looking version of Rashi script.

Comment: @ezra, I mean, Koren's legibility concerns led him to change the forms of some of the letters to look more like Ashurit

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The Open Siddur Project has a nice font pack with many great fonts available to be downloaded for free on their site. One of the included fonts is called Mekorot Rashi, and it supports nikkud. I have downloaded these fonts and I must say they are incredibly useful.  Check them out [here](https://opensiddur.org/help/fonts/).

Comment: The download link is towards the bottom - search for ZIP. (Direct link: https://github.com/aharonium/fonts/archive/master.zip)